# How to Calculate the Out of Office Hours In Salesforce

Tags: apex, businesshours

I have the three field like below and I want to calculate the number of out of office hours.

**Office hour is : 9:00 to 18:00**

**Fields :**

In Time : date time field
Out Time : date time field

No. of Out of Office Hour : ?

ex:

```
My Office hour is : 9:00 to 18:00

Fields :
In Time : date time field 
Out Time : date time field
No. of Out of Office Hour : ?

Sample Answer : 
In time : 1-1-2014 19:00 
Out time : 1-2-2014 07:00
No. of Out of Office Hour :0 day 12 hrs.
```

Kindly let us know, how to calculate in apex trigger / class

Comment: From 7pm on January the 1st to 7am on January the 2nd is only [12 hours](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=1&y1=2014&d2=2&m2=1&y2=2014&h1=19&i1=0&s1=0&h2=7&i2=0&s2=0). How can "No. of Out of Office Hour" be "1 day 12 hrs 30 mins."?

Comment: The image that you edited in seems like a separate question. If so, it should be asked independently of this question.

Comment: The answer I've given below gives 12 hours for the example input in and out date times. Is there a problem with the answer? If so, please give an example of the in and out date times and the expected answer. Do you want to exclude Saturday and Sunday hours even though they are included in your sample Business Hours?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [BusinessHours.diff(String, Datetime, Datetime)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_businesshours.htm#apex_System_BusinessHours_diff) method.

> Returns the difference between a start and end Datetime based on a specific set of business hours.

**NOTE** : The following examples assume that the current user is in the the same timezone as the BusinessHours. If not, you will need to correct via GMT/UTC.

```
// Get the default business hours
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id, MondayStartTime, MondayEndTime, TuesdayStartTime, TuesdayEndTime, TimeZoneSidKey FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];

Datetime inTime = Datetime.newInstance(2014, 1, 1, 19, 0, 0);
System.assert(!BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, inTime));
Datetime outTime = Datetime.newInstance(2014, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0);
System.assert(!BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, outTime), outTime.format() + ' GMT: '+ outTime.timeGMT()+ ' expected to be out of business hours' + bh);
long businessMillisecondsDiff = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, inTime, outTime);
decimal businessHoursDiff = businessMillisecondsDiff / (1000.0*60.0*60.0);

// The get the time difference and convert from milliseconds to hours.
decimal totalHoursDiff = (outTime.getTime() - inTime.getTime()) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0); 
System.assertEquals(12.0, totalHoursDiff);

decimal outOfBusinessHours = totalHoursDiff - businessHoursDiff;
System.debug('totalHoursDiff:' + totalHoursDiff +
             '\n businessHoursDiff: ' + businessHoursDiff + 
             '\n outOfBusinessHours:' + outOfBusinessHours);
```

> totalHoursDiff:12
>    businessHoursDiff: 0E+3
>    outOfBusinessHours:12

The following separate test also works:

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id, MondayStartTime, MondayEndTime, TuesdayStartTime, TuesdayEndTime, TimeZoneSidKey FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];

Datetime inTime = Datetime.newInstance(2014, 1, 6, 11, 0, 0);
System.assert(BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, inTime));
Datetime outTime = Datetime.newInstance(2014, 1, 6, 20, 0, 0);
System.assert(!BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, outTime), outTime.format() + ' GMT: '+     outTime.timeGMT()+ ' expected to be out of business hours' + bh);
long businessMillisecondsDiff = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, inTime, outTime);
decimal businessHoursDiff = businessMillisecondsDiff / (1000.0*60.0*60.0);

// The get the time difference and convert from milliseconds to hours.
decimal totalHoursDiff = (outTime.getTime() - inTime.getTime()) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0); 
System.assertEquals(9.0, totalHoursDiff);

decimal outOfBusinessHours = totalHoursDiff - businessHoursDiff;
System.debug('totalHoursDiff:' + totalHoursDiff +
             '\n businessHoursDiff: ' + businessHoursDiff + 
             '\n outOfBusinessHours:' + outOfBusinessHours);
```

> totalHoursDiff:9
>    businessHoursDiff: 7
>    outOfBusinessHours:2

Comment: @RickyMartin I've made some corrections to how the `totalHoursDiff ` is calculated.

Comment: @RickyMartin Did you see my comments on the question above? Your example no longer makes sense and you have asked a separate question.

Comment: @RickyMartin Maybe you could provide more examples of what you are trying to accomplish? Ideally show all time periods involved and what you expect the outcome of the calculation to be.

Comment: @RickyMartin From what I can tell you have significantly changed the objective of the question. At this stage I would suggest you rollback your changes and ask a new question about holiday hours.

Comment: i have posted new question as http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45738/how-to-calculate-the-office-hours-except-teh-holidays-hours-in-salesforce

Comment: please look above link and guide me