# How to Calculate the Office Hours except holidays hours In Salesforce

Tags: apex, businesshours, holidays

I have the three field like below and I want to calculate the  business hours but need to reduce the hour if the exist the holiday.

I have write this code into the apex class and call this class form the trigger after update.

```
 BusinessHours bh = [SELECT id  From BusinessHours 
   Where IsDefault=true];

Datetime inTime = custom date time field 1
Datetime outTime = Custom date time field 2;

long businessMillisecondsDiff = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, inTime, outTime);
decimal businessHoursDiff = businessMillisecondsDiff / (1000.0*60.0*60.0);

custom_text_field__c = businessHoursDiff + 'Hours';
```

Office hour : 9 to 5 pm

> Output :
>
> intime = 01/01/2013 9:00 AM
>
> out time = 03/01/2013 10:00 PM
>
> Note; 2/1/2103 is holiday
>
> Expected output is : 16 hours

**My question is :**

If we added the holiday by using the setup, how to reduce that holiday
hours?
Thanks

Comment: What type of Datetime ranges are you expecting to have? Hours, Days, Months, Years between the in and out times? There is the [BusinessHours.isWithin(string, Datetime)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_businesshours.htm#apex_System_BusinessHours_isWithin) method, which will include holidays in the calculation. However, it will only tell you is a certain point in time is a holiday.

Comment: what exactly you mean by "how to reduce the holiday hours ?" with your example, are you setting up the holiday on 1/1/2013 and then trying to find the difference ?

Comment: Amended the question @Vamsi Krishna

Comment: did you try running your code in Developer Console ? the whole point of calling the diff method with a businessHourId is to calculate the difference based on the business hours considering holidays as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old to migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleasee use following code:

```
public with sharing class time_calculation {

    public static String segment_text(String segment_string, Integer segment_integer, String prior_segments) {
        String return_string; //string for returning
        String spacer = ''; //string for holding an additional spacer
        if (segment_string != 'Second') { //if the segment being determined is not Seconds
            spacer = ' '; //create a spacer value
        }
        if (segment_integer > 1) { //if the value is greater than 1
            return_string = segment_integer.format()+' '+segment_string+'s'+spacer; //format
        } else if (segment_integer > 0) { //if the value is greater than 0
            return_string = segment_integer.format()+' '+segment_string+spacer; //format
        } else { //otherwise
            if (prior_segments != '' || segment_string == 'Second') { //if there is a value for prior segments or this is the seconds segment
                return_string = '0 '+segment_string+'s'+spacer; //format
            } else {
                return_string = ''; //set variable to null
            }
        }
        return return_string; //pass back the string
    }

    public static String duration_between_two_date_times(DateTime start_date_time, DateTime end_date_time) {
        Integer start_year_as_int = start_date_time.year(); //grab the start year
        Integer start_day_as_int = start_date_time.dayOfYear(); //grab the start day
        Integer start_hour_as_int = start_date_time.hour(); //grab the start hour
        Integer start_minute_as_int = start_date_time.minute(); //grab the start minute
        Integer start_second_as_int = start_date_time.second(); //grab the start second
        Integer start_in_seconds = (start_year_as_int * 31556926) + (start_day_as_int * 86400) + (start_hour_as_int * 3600) + (start_minute_as_int * 60) + (start_second_as_int * 1); //convert the start date to a value in seconds
        //there are 31556926 seconds in one year and that is why we are mutiplying the start_year_as_int value by 31556926 > this same logic applies to the days, hours & minutes logic which is why there are weird multipliers in that line of code
        Integer end_year_as_int = end_date_time.year(); //grab the end year
        Integer end_day_as_int = end_date_time.dayOfYear(); //grab the end day
        Integer end_hour_as_int = end_date_time.hour(); //grab the end hour
        Integer end_minute_as_int = end_date_time.minute(); //grab the end minute
        Integer end_second_as_int = end_date_time.second(); //grab the end second
        Integer end_in_seconds = (end_year_as_int * 31556926) + (end_day_as_int * 86400) + (end_hour_as_int * 3600) + (end_minute_as_int * 60) + (end_second_as_int * 1); //convert the end date to a value in seconds
        Integer total_duration_in_seconds = end_in_seconds - start_in_seconds; //duration in seconds
        Integer year_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/31556926).intValue(),10000000); //number of years
        Integer day_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/86400).intValue(),365); //number of days
        Integer hour_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/3600).intValue(),24); //number of hours
        Integer minute_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/60).intValue(),60); //number of minutes
        Integer second_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/1).intValue(),60); //number of seconds

        String year_text_string = segment_text('Year', year_result, ''); //string variable for text regarding Year
        String day_text_string = segment_text('Day', day_result, year_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Day
        String hour_text_string = segment_text('Hour', hour_result, year_text_string + day_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Hour
        String minute_text_string = segment_text('Minute', minute_result, year_text_string + day_text_string + hour_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Minute
        String second_text_string = segment_text('Second', second_result, year_text_string + day_text_string + hour_text_string + minute_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Second
        String return_string = year_text_string + day_text_string + hour_text_string + minute_text_string + second_text_string;//concatenate all the strings into one for our resutling test string
        return return_string; //pass back the final string
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below the code to find.

```
  public Integer calculateWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(Date date1,Date date2){

               List<Holiday> holidays=[Select h.StartTimeInMinutes, h.Name, h.ActivityDate From Holiday h];

                Integer allDaysBetween = date1.daysBetween(date2);
                Integer allWorkingDays=0;
                for(Integer k=0;k<allDaysBetween ;k++ ){
                    if(checkifItisWorkingDay(date1.addDays(k),holidays)){
                        allWorkingDays++;
                    } 
                }

                return allWorkingDays;

      }

public boolean checkifItisWorkingDay(Date currentDate,List<Holiday> holidays){
                 Date weekStart  = currentDate.toStartofWeek();
                for(Holiday hDay:holidays){
                        if(currentDate.daysBetween(hDay.ActivityDate) == 0){
                                 return false;
                        }
                }
               if(weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) ==0 || weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) == 6){
                       return false;
                } else 
                       return true;
  }
```